# why is sharelatex not compiling and giving this error?

Tags: errors, compiling

"Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log."

Comment: my magic 8-ball says: "Please provide MWE."

Comment: ... or make your sharelatex project public, read-only, then give us the link, see https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Sharing_your_work_with_others

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. here is the link  https://www.sharelatex.com/project/578919bcf1b8fda211a695f4

Comment: You have been asked for a MWE in the last question (which was closed) and honestly this one should be closed as well in its current state. Please improve the question.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your specific error, but I had this error pop up when one of my images (pdf) were corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

So I've downloaded the .log file and found a couple of things. It starts on line 1192 (of that log file). Something is wrong with your math environment. I think I traced your problem back to the file `02.mehthod_ch2.tex` on line 111-113.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
      rs_{f}(x,y) =|{(\prod_{i=1}(s_{\lambda_{i}},\sigma_{i},\rho_{i},\phi_{i}(x,y)^_\omega_{i})^_{1/\sum^{|s_{f}|}_{i=1}\omega_{i}}}}|  
\end{eqnarray}
```

I can only guess what you want to write there. I corrected some of the obvious mistakes: you can not do something like `x^_y` where this happend i inserted a question mark. You also used double subscript withoud {} e.g. `x_y_z` instead of `x_{y_z}`. I also added some `\left... \right...` to your Braces and the |. The code now looks like this:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
rs_{f}(x,y)=
    \left|
        \left(
            \prod_{i=1}
            \left(s_{\lambda_{i}},\sigma_{i},\rho_{i},\phi_{i}(x,y)^?_{\omega_{i}}
            \right)^?_{1/\sum^{|s_{f}|}_{i=1}\omega_{i}}
        \right)
    \right|
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

And produces this result:[image]
Is that what you want? If not please post a picture of the desired formular, so we can help you get there.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i wanted it just like this. I also have problems with my usage of subfigures. in the same code. Could you pls help me with that.

Comment: Please open another question with the precise description of your problem and a MWE (minimal working example) of this area. Just posting a sharelatex link to the whole projekt is not very helpful since everybody has to put in allot of effort just to understand whats going on. If you are not sure of how to write a question take a look at the help section or just "do it like the others do".

Comment: thank you very much. yes i find it hard to express my problem, i will try to do it as a different question.